# how to append a cell to a table row in js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

```
$("#requesttable").append("<center><legend><h2>Remote Stop</h2></legend></center><tr><td><B>Transaction ID</B></td><td><input id='transactionIdremtestop' class='easyui-textbox' name='transactionIdremtestop' style='width:200px;'></td></tr>");
```

I have to append this code in javascript.

```
This part is working but html textbox is showing instead of 'easyui-textbox'..how can i make it..to show easyui textbox
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Not only is `<center>` deprecated for years, you can't have that or `<legend>` is the child of `<table>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am getting you right, it's just the double quotes that's bothering you. Though I am not sure it works, I am just modifying your own code here:

```
$("#canclresv").append('<center><legend><h2>Cancel Reservation</h2></legend></center><tr><td><input id="keygetconfig" class="easyui-textbox" name="keygetconfig" style="width:200px;"></td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 0):

give an id to the table like id="table" then

```js
 document.getElementById("table").rows[0].insertCell(-1).innerHTML +="whatever you want";
```

if you want to insert in an already existing cell just use:

```js
 document.getElementById("table").rows[0].cells[index].innerHTML ="whatever you want";
```